# Why printf() when printing multiple strings (%s) leaves newline and how to solve this?

Tags: c, arrays, string, printf

I made a program which accepts strings (first/last names) but instead of a typical output of 
 Phil Snowken age 3 , i am getting 
Phil
Snowken

age 3

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define N 10
struct data{
char fname[30];
char lname[30];
int age;
};

main()
{
    int i;
    struct data base[N];
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        printf("\n-------------------------");
        printf("\nPeople Data(%d remaining)\n",N-i);
        printf("---------------------------\n\n");
        printf("\nFirst Name ");
        fgets(base[i].fname,30,stdin);
        printf("\nLast Name ");
        fgets(base[i].lname,30,stdin);
        printf("\nAge ");
        scanf(" %d",&(base[i].age));
        fflush(stdin);
    }

    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        printf("%s %s Year:(%d)",base[i].fname,base[i].lname,base[i].age);
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: This could be a compiler issue I am not certain

Comment: `fgets()` reads in at most one less than *size* characters from *stream* and stores them into the buffer pointed to by *s*. Reading stops after an EOF or a newline. **If a newline is read, it is stored into the buffer.**

Comment: Remove `fflush(stdin)`. It invokes undefined behavior.

Comment: @haccks why? it does a great work ignoring '\n' but the devious scanf() which leaves it to buffer

Comment: @haccks: The behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is not defined by the C language. Whatever it happens to do under the implementation you're using, it could behave completely differently under a different one. Whatever `fflush(stdin)` is supposed to do, there's likely a better way to do it, such as reading and discarding characters until you see `'\n'` or `EOF`.

Comment: @KeithThompson; It invokes UB if not used under MS-DOS. (AFAIK).

Comment: @haccks: As far as the C standard is concerned, the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` is simply undefined; undefined behavior is not conditional. Whatever MS-DOS happens to do is by definition consistent with that. Other systems and standards may happen to define the behavior, but depending on any such definition makes your code non-portable (and, in this case, is unnecessary). I just now learned that [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fflush.html) does define the behavior of `fflush(stdin)` if `stdin` is seekable and not at end-of-file, so it's not just MS-DOS.

Comment: @KeithThompson; Thanks for informing about POSIX. But you can't use this on Linux/UNIX.

Comment: @haccks: [POSIX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) is not an OS, it's a standard "Portable Operating System Interface". Linux and UNIX systems conform to POSIX, or at least try to do so. So yes, `fflush(stdin)` has defined behavior (defined by POSIX and by the OS, but not by the ISO C standard) on Linux-based and UNIX-based systems, assuming they conform sufficiently well to POSIX. Nevertheless, using it is IMHO a bad idea.

Comment: @KeithThompson; In what circumstances `fflush(stdin)` invoke UB?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45552/discussion-between-keith-thompson-and-haccks)

Comment: Note: The space before `"%d"` in `scanf(" %d",&(base[i].age));` is not needed.  No harm leaving it there, just that it is redundant.  `"%d"` consumes leading white-space.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`fgets()` reads newlines with the string entered, so each time you press enter it gets the `\n` also read into string (see [man fgets](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fgets))

You have to check the last character and if it's `\n` change it to `\0`, like that:

```
size_t length = strlen(base[i].fname);
if (base[i].fname[length-1] == '\n')
    base[i].fname[length-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: How about if I declare `length` as `int`?

Comment: @niCk it will work, you will probably get a compilation warning though because `strlen` returns `size_t`

Comment: @prajmus: There's an implicit conversion from `size_t` to `int`, so a warning is unlikely. niCk: But why would you want to declare `length` as an `int`? It probably won't cause any problems, but it just makes more sense for it to be a `size_t`.

Comment: @KeithThompson I have not read that much for size_t to be able to justify it at the exam , and besides I am limited to what libraries I am allowed to use

Comment: @niCk size_t is basically an unsigned integer, and you don't have to use any additional libraries, it's defined in C standard. It will be available for you after you include `stdio.h`

Comment: @niCk: prajmus is correct -- but if you're more comfortable using `int`, it's not quite as clean but it's ok for an introductory sample program like this.